# How to auto-login website in chrome with saved password

Tags: google-chrome, autologin

Chrome is auto-filling the credentials, but not log me in until I click login. How to automate? (windows, non-google websites).

Comment: Do not auto-login. First, everything automated is very bad. Automation does not let the user to do things like check/uncheck Remember me box, or interact with other input fields. Second, automation is good from a very narrow perspective. Despite most of the users want the automation, there will be always lots of people who will be annoyed by the unwanted, automated step(s). It's like having no control over the happenings.

Answer (score 15):

Using the Chrome Identity API you can have Chrome (on desktop and Android) automatically attempt to log in the user when they hit your page, even if their session has expired.

Following is a workflow diagram of how it works, but the details can be found in the [Google Authentication API: Let the user automatically sign back in](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/credential-management-api#let_the_user_automatically_sign_back_in) section:

[image: Workflow example]

Answer (score 1):

It is not the browser's responsibility to auto-login to websites. This is the responsibility of the website you are accessing. The browser can remember form data and auto-fill for you, as can various extensions like LastPass.

However, in order to actually auto-login, you must first login to the website you are trying to access and enable the option they provide, often called 'Remember me?'. The website would typically use a cookie to store the credentials (securely with a hash + salt), and if the cookie still exists (not cleared from the browser or expired), and the hash of real password in database matches the one in the cookie, the website will auto-login.

You could force the browser to try and auto-login with extensions, which are essentially macros. You could try [Auto Login](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-login/kjdgohfkopafhjmmlbojhaabfpndllgk) or [iMacros](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp?hl=en) extensions for this. I would generally avoid this though.

Comment: Any way to click submit button automatically? like VBScript or batch file, i.e, without extensions? or any chrome settings flag...

Comment: This isn't what the user was asking for. They're asking how to automatically click submit on websites that *don't* have an autologin feature.

Auto Login or iMacro are ok suggestions, but you should give more detail about why you don't recommend them.

Answer (score -1):

Anyone else stumbling into this thread from a google search.... you can do this with autohotkey. If you browse to yourbankhere.com and chrome fills in the user/pass, you can have autohotkey perform a mousemove then a mouseclick to click the login button.